# how to get mime type of file in asp .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, angular8

i am working with uploaded file preview in angular 8.. i have uploaded my files into local disc.. from there i need to get file content and preview.. I am able to preview pdf but only after converting to base64. I need to get mime type.. how to modify my method for that?

```
public IActionResult GetFileUploads(string filename)
        {
            List<FileUpload> obj = new List<FileUpload>();
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\Uploads", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                byte[] imageByteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(imageByteData);
                string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64Data);

                FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                var fileName = fi.Name;
                fileUpload.DocumentURL = imageDataURL;
                fileUpload.DocumentName = fileName;

                obj.Add(fileUpload);
            }
          return  ReturnHttpOKResult(obj);
        }
```